Create matrix report with three arrays
I have three arrays:
$companyX = [
        0 => [ 2 => 'company X', 107 => 'Accounts receivable', 2000 => 'Provider A', 'amount' => 2 ],
        1 => [ 2 => 'company X', 107 => 'Accounts receivable', 4123 => 'Provider F', 'amount' => 5 ],
        2 => [ 2 => 'company X', 205 => 'Accounts payable',    2000 => 'Provider A', 'amount' => 2 ],
        3 => [ 2 => 'company X', 205 => 'Accounts payable',    4123 => 'Provider F', 'amount' => 7 ],
        4 => [ 2 => 'company X', 603 => 'Sales',               2011 => 'Provider G', 'amount' => 9 ]
    ];

    $companyY = [
        0 => [ 5 => 'company Y', 107 => 'Accounts receivable', 2000 => 'Provider A', 'amount' => 15 ], 
        1 => [ 5 => 'company Y', 107 => 'Accounts receivable', 4123 => 'Provider F', 'amount' => 21 ], 
        2 => [ 5 => 'company Y', 205 => 'Accounts payable',    2000 => 'Provider A', 'amount' => 36 ], 
        3 => [ 5 => 'company Y', 205 => 'Accounts payable',    4123 => 'Provider F', 'amount' => 47 ],
        4 => [ 5 => 'company Y', 701 => 'Costs',               6360 => 'Provider K', 'amount' => 14 ]
    ];

    $companyZ = [
        0 => [ 8 => 'company Z', 107 => 'Accounts receivable', 2000 => 'Provider A', 'amount' => 51 ],
        1 => [ 8 => 'company Z', 107 => 'Accounts receivable', 4123 => 'Provider F', 'amount' => 63 ],
        2 => [ 8 => 'company Z', 205 => 'Accounts payable',    2000 => 'Provider A', 'amount' => 74 ],
        3 => [ 8 => 'company Z', 205 => 'Accounts payable',    4123 => 'Provider F', 'amount' => 83 ]
    ];

I hope to get the next report:

I tried the following but it's not what I expected:
$group = [...$companyX, ...$companY, ...$companyZ ];

    ?>

    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <td>Company</td>
            <td>Account</td>
            <td>Provider</td>
            <td>Amount</td>
        </tr>
        <?php foreach ($group as $key => $detail) : ?>
        <tr>
            <?php foreach ($detail as $dt) : ?>
                    <td><?php echo  $dt; ?></td>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </tr> 
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </table>
    

Company         Account             Provider    Amount
company X   Accounts receivable Provider A  2
company X   Accounts receivable Provider F  5
company X   Accounts payable    Provider A  2
company X   Accounts payable    Provider F  7
company X   Sales                   Provider G  9
company Y   Accounts receivable Provider A  15
company Y   Accounts receivable Provider F  21
company Y   Accounts payable    Provider A  36
company Y   Accounts payable    Provider F  47
company Y   Costs                   Provider K  14
company Z   Accounts receivable Provider A  51
company Z   Accounts receivable Provider F  63
company Z   Accounts payable    Provider A  74
company Z   Accounts payable    Provider F  83


I'd start by reorganizing that data, into something like this: https://3v4l.org/AkpFr That should be quite easy to loop over, to create your desired output structure. If you want, to can sort by the keys on first and second level afterwards, so that those don't come in order depending on the input data. You'll have to check if an entry for a specific company is set, otherwise output -. And if you need this dynamic, regarding the companies, you will also have to collect all occurring companies, while reorganizing the data.

If I add this element to the array $companyY:  [ 5 => 'company Y', 701 => 'Costs',               6360 => 'Provider K', 'amount' => 566 ] .          table overflows:                 Costs Provider K  -  $566.00  -   -   -   -   -  $599.00

Provided you know the codes for your data keys, the amount of companies and their names, etc... you could reference it as you loop over a restructured array. Though this is likely not the most eloquent or dynamic answer it gets the job done.
    $companies = [...$companyX, ...$companyY, ...$companyZ];
    $data = ['Accounts payable', 'Accounts receivable', 'Costs', 'Sales'];

    function returnPayable($data, $companies) {
        $compKeys = [2,5,8];
        $providerKeys = [2000, 2011, 4123, 6360];
        $payable = [];
        $company = '-';
        foreach($companies as $arr){  
            foreach($data as $v2){
                if(in_array($v2, $arr)) {
                    foreach($arr as $k => $v) {
                        if(in_array($k, $compKeys)) {
                            $company = $v;
                        }
                        if(in_array($k, $providerKeys)) {
                            $payable[$v2][$v][] = [$company => $arr['amount']];                                                
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return $payable;
    }  

This will return a nested array with the Account column as parent key with provider and company data as nested arrays.
Then you can iterate over the new array and use helper arrays to compare your data and output it into the table.
    // save the array call to a variable
    $list = returnPayable($data, $companies);
    // output variable to build table
    $output = "
    <table> 
        <tr>
            <th>Account</th>
            <th>Provider</th>
            <th>Company X</th>
            <th>Company Y</th>
            <th>Company Z</th>
        </tr>";
    // iterate over the array
    foreach($list as $account => $row){
        $output .= '<tr>';
        // get the account and provider
        foreach($row as $provider => $company){
            $output .= "<td>$account</td>";
            $output .= "<td>$provider</td>";
            // check the count of the companies is less than three
            // company X, Y and Z = 3
            foreach($company as $val){
                // conditional to get the name and amount
                if(count($company) < 3) {
                    // probably a better way to do this dynamically
                    foreach($v3 as $k3 => $v4){
                        $k3 === 'company X' ? $output .= "<td>usd".number_format($v4, 2, '.', '')."</td>" : $output .= "<td> - </td>";
                        $k3 === 'company Y' ? $output .= "<td>usd".number_format($v4, 2, '.', '')."</td>" : $output .= "<td> - </td>";
                        $k3 === 'company Z' ? $output .= "<td>usd".number_format($v4, 2, '.', '')."</td>" : $output .= "<td> - </td>";
                    }
                }else{
                    foreach($v3 as $k3 => $v4){
                        $output .= "<td>usd".number_format($v4, 2, '.', '')."</td>";
                    }
                }
            }
        $output .= "</tr>";
        }
    }
    $output .= "</table>";
    return $output;


Working snipit on PHP Sandbox
